# How to detect a click on a drag and drop object in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, drag-and-drop, click

I'm building a flash app that has some draggable buttons on it and I want them to behave like this:

- You click on it, ClickEvent1 happens,
- You click and hold on the button, you
  can move it.  If you release from the
  hold, it does NOT trigger the
  ClickEvent

I'm running into the logic problem of not knowing whether a user is just clicking or starting a drag event. Does anyone know any logic to get around this issue?  I have thought of alternatives such as placing regions of the button that are only draggable or only clickable, but I've seen this type of functionality in other flash apps and I'm wondering how it is accomplished.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another approach could be the interval between mousedown and mouseup - a drag will take longer than a click.

Comment: Much better answer than checking if the mouse has moved. A click is fast, a drag is a longer event, some users might not be able to click without moving, especially tablet or touch screen users, or people with really fast mice.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes the most obvious insights only find their way into my brain in the shower...

I realized the easiest way to accomplish this is just by keeping track of the mouse coordinates when the MOUSE_DOWN is first registered.  Then when the MOUSE_UP event occurs, you just check to see if the mouse coordinates are the same or if the mouse position has changed.  If the mouse hasn't moved, then the user is clicking the object, if the mouse has moved, then you know the user dragged the object so they are not clicking.

Comment: I think you'd need a degree of tolerance in there as the mouse may have moved slightly even when the user 'clicks'. I use a tablet and it's really hard to not move the cursor when clicking.

Comment: agreed.  +/- a few px.  I think your time interval solution is a better all around solution though :)